# Symfony4 vardumper server must implement DataDumperInterface error

Tags: symfony, debugging, var-dump

In Symfony 4, I'm trying to use the [Symfony VarDumper](https://symfony.com/components/VarDumper) component and more specifically the [VarDumper server](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-vardumper-server).

I installed the following packages:

```
composer require debug --dev
composer require symfony/debug-bundle --dev
composer require symfony/var-dumper --dev
```

started the server:

```
./bin/console server:dump
```

and added a dump in my code

```
dump($entity);
```

but the server runs without anything getting printed in the console and whats more problematic, the code now actually fails printing this error:

```
Type error: Argument 5 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\DumpDataCollector::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\DataDumperInterface or be null, instance of Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Server\Connection given
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Exact Symfony version?  4.1.0 had a problem with the dump server.  I tested 4.1.1 a few days ago and it worked okay using website-skeleton as a starting point.  And no need to install debug and var-dumper components explicitly.  The debug-bundle will take care of that.

Comment: Just did a clean install with the skeleton,debug-bundle and server.  All seems to work as expected.

Comment: OK, I'm using Symfony 4.0.4, I'll try upgrading it right away

Comment: Thank you very much, upgrading Symfony fixed the issue.

Comment: The [dump server](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-vardumper-server) was only introduced in 4.1.  I'm surprised 4.0 even had the server:dump command in it.  But glad it is working.

Comment: Yes it's true I read that, now the error actually makes a little more sens. I just figured since the command was available I must have been in the right version and didn't bother confirm it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cerad put me on the right track. The dump server was introduced in version 4.1 but the command was available even though I was in 4.0.4. Maybe due to the packages I installed manually (var-dumper). A Symfony update to 4.1 fixed my issue.

Thanks